# How to pass selected data from a PopUpTableViewController to other TableViewController in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, popup

I have 2 View Controllers: In the first ViewController that has a TableView, I have a button in each TableViewCell to select a shipping option. When clicking the button, another TableViewController will pop up with a list of shipping options. Upon choosing a shipping option, I need to pass this data back to TableViewCell in the first ViewController. I wrote below code but the shipping option selected in the second TableViewController still didn't pass to the first controller. Other things work fine. Could anyone help to let me know how to improve this code? Thanks a million!

//First ViewController:

```
class PaymentMethodViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    //MARK: - IBOutlets

    @IBOutlet weak var PurchasedReviewItemsTableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PurchasedReviewItemsTableViewCell") as! PurchasedReviewItemsTableViewCell

        cell.delegate = self

    }

}

extension PaymentMethodViewController: PurchasedReviewItemsTableViewCellDelegate {

    func chooseShippingOptionButtonPressed() {

        let chooseShippingOptionVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "ShippingOptionsSelectionPopUpViewController") as! ShippingOptionsSelectionPopUpViewController

        chooseShippingOptionVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

        self.present(chooseShippingOptionVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //MARK: Pass data from popUpView

    func popUpShippingOptionsSelected(shippingOption: String) {

        let cell = PurchasedReviewItemsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PurchasedReviewItemsTableViewCell") as! PurchasedReviewItemsTableViewCell
        cell.shippingOptionsLabel.text = shippingOption

    }

}
```

//TableViewCell of the first ViewController:

```
protocol PurchasedReviewItemsTableViewCellDelegate {

    func chooseShippingOptionButtonPressed()

    func popUpShippingOptionsSelected(shippingOption: String)
}


class PurchasedReviewItemsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var shippingOptionsLabel: UILabel!

    var delegate: PurchasedReviewItemsTableViewCellDelegate?
    @IBAction func changeShippingOptionButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        delegate?.chooseShippingOptionButtonPressed()   
    }

}
```

//Second TableViewController:

```
class ShippingOptionsSelectionPopUpViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var selectedShippingOption : String?

    var shippingOption = ["X", "Y"]

    var delegate: ShippingOptionsSelectionPopUpDelegate?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShippingOptionsSelectionPopUpTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ShippingOptionsSelectionPopUpTableViewCell

        cell.selectShippingOption(shippingOption: shippingOption[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        selectedShippingOption = shippingOption[indexPath.row]

        delegate?.popUpShippingOptionsSelected(shippingOption: selectedShippingOption!)

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define separate protocol for popUpShippingOptionsSelected

```
protocol ShippingOptionsDelegate {

func popUpShippingOptionsSelected(shippingOption: String)
}

class ShippingOptionsSelectionPopUpViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var selectedShippingOption : String?

var shippingOption = ["X", "Y"]

var shippingOptiondelegate: ShippingOptionsSelectionPopUpDelegate?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            2
        }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShippingOptionsSelectionPopUpTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ShippingOptionsSelectionPopUpTableViewCell

        cell.selectShippingOption(shippingOption: shippingOption[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        selectedShippingOption = shippingOption[indexPath.row]

        shippingOptiondelegate?.popUpShippingOptionsSelected(shippingOption: selectedShippingOption!)

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
}
```

Add tag to cell

```
class PaymentMethodViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

//MARK: - IBOutlets

@IBOutlet weak var PurchasedReviewItemsTableView: UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return 5
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PurchasedReviewItemsTableViewCell") as! PurchasedReviewItemsTableViewCell

cell.delegate = self
cell.tag = 100 // Set tag

}

}
```

Update extension with ShippingOptionsDelegate

```
extension PaymentMethodViewController: PurchasedReviewItemsTableViewCellDelegate, ShippingOptionsDelegate  {

func chooseShippingOptionButtonPressed() {

            let chooseShippingOptionVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "ShippingOptionsSelectionPopUpViewController") as! ShippingOptionsSelectionPopUpViewController
             chooseShippingOptionVC.shippingOptiondelegate = self
             chooseShippingOptionVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

             self.present(chooseShippingOptionVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//MARK: Pass data from popUpView

func popUpShippingOptionsSelected(shippingOption: String) {

        let cell = PurchasedReviewItemsTableView.viewWithTag(100) as! PurchasedReviewItemsTableViewCell // use tag to get cell
        cell.shippingOptionsLabel.text = shippingOption

}

}
```